# How to apply half a color filter to image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, filter, bootstrap-5

I'm currently coding a new website for my business as our current one is outdated, using the mock-up our graphics designer created for us. I'm a little stuck on how I go about adding a filter to the image, like the following example, and wondered if someone on here could help me? Google seems to be of no use, sadly.

[image: Example of filter I mean]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overlay a semi-transparent gradient over the element.

```css
.filter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #001f3f, transparent);
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/5VSUqlS.png" width="300px" />
  <div class="filter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. You're an absolute lifesaver :D